# How to format jQuery .map() with keys and values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create array with keys and values by using the jQuery .map().
When I use my code I have a problem with formatting:

```
["name1:1", "name2:1", "name3:0"]
```

I need:

```
['name1':1,'name2':1,'name3':0]
```

I spend a few hours to make it work, but I don't know what is wrong.

HTML

```
<div class="inputs-container">
    <input id="name1" name="name1" type="checkbox" class="multicheckbox-item" value="1" checked="checked">
    <input id="name2" name="name2" type="checkbox" class="multicheckbox-item" value="1" checked="checked">
    <input id="name3" name="name3" type="checkbox" class="multicheckbox-item" value="0">
</div>
```

JS

```
var inputsContainer = $('.inputs-container');

var inputValues = inputsContainer.find( 'input.multicheckbox-item' ).map( function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var active = 0;
    if( $(this).prop( 'checked' ) ){
        var active = 1;
    }
    return name + ':' + active;
}).get();

console.log( inputValues );
```

Comment: `return {[name]: active};` to get an array of objects, which is probably what you want. What you say you "need" is not really a JavaScript structure.

Comment: You’re doing string concatenation, and then you wonder that you get strings as a result?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want an object and `.each` (or `.forEach` in native array terms).

```
var inputsContainer = $('.inputs-container');
var inputValues = {};

var inputValues = inputsContainer.find('input.multicheckbox-item').each( function() {
    inputValues[$(this).attr('name')] = ($(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0);
});

console.log(inputValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var inputsContainer = $('.inputs-container');

var inputValues_key = inputsContainer.find( 'input.multicheckbox-item' ).map(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    return name;
}).get();

var inputValues_value = inputsContainer.find( 'input.multicheckbox-item' ).map(function() {
    var active = $(this).prop('checked')? 1 : 0;
    return active;
}).get();


var inputValues = [], length = Math.min(inputValues_key.length, inputValues_value.length);
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    inputValues.push([inputValues_key[i], inputValues_value[i]]);
}
console.log( inputValues );
```